# C++ Nested class template Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'type' to 'same type'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, inner-classes

I get 2 (probably) identical errors on the below code:

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'HashTable::HashTableEntry *' to 'HashTable::HashTableEntry *'`
Error C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'HashTable::HashTableEntry *' to 'HashTable::HashTableEntry *'
```

It occurs in my `HashTable` class, `rehash()` function. Here's the code snippet below:

```
template<class T, class V>
class HashTable {
private:
    template<class T, class V> struct HashTableEntry {
        T key;
        V value;
    };
    ...
    int size;
    int capacity;
    HashTableEntry<T,V>* A;
public:
    // ctor
    HashTable(int cap) :
        size(0), capacity(cap), A(new HashTableEntry<T,V>[cap])
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
    template<typename T, typename V> void rehash()
    {
        ...
        HashTableEntry<T,V>* newMemoryRegion = new HashTableEntry<T,V>[capacity];
        HashTableEntry<T,V>* disposable = A; // FIRST ERROR HERE
        A = newMemoryRegion;                 // SECOND ERROR HERE
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

What I'm trying to do (as you probably realized) is get `disposable` to point to `A`'s memory address and then `A` to point to `newMemoryRegion`'s address.

I tried to `static_cast<>` them - no good. Then I took out the nested class - still same errors. Finally I tried `reinterpret_cast<>` and the first error (initialization) was gone, however the second error strangely persists:

```
HashTableEntry<T,V>* disposable = reinterpret_cast<HashTableEntry<T, V>*>(A); // no more errors here
A = reinterpret_cast<HashTableEntry<T, V>*>(newMemoryRegion); // SAME SECOND ERROR persists here
```

Why is this happening? How can I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are `HashTableEntry` and `rehash()` templated with their own parameters that mirror the template parameters of `HashTable`? You should remove the templates from `HashTableEntry` and `rehash()` and let them inherit the parameters from `HashTable` instead:

```
template<class T, class V>
class HashTable {
private:
    struct HashTableEntry {
        T key;
        V value;
    };
    ...
    int size;
    int capacity;
    HashTableEntry* A;
public:
    // ctor
    HashTable(int cap) :
        size(0), capacity(cap), A(new HashTableEntry[cap])
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
    void rehash()
    {
        ...
        HashTableEntry* newMemoryRegion = new HashTableEntry[capacity];
        HashTableEntry* disposable = A;
        A = newMemoryRegion;
        ...
    }
    ...
};
```